# Interpreting the Gaussian Integral

Tags: real-analysis, statistics

I am having trouble understanding a result on Gaussian integrals that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{\langle AX, X\rangle} \,dX = \sqrt{(2\pi)^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{\langle-(1/2I-A)x, x\rangle} \, dx$$

for a symmetric matrix $A$.

I don't see how the transformation is made.

Comment: Doesn't seem true. Consider $n=1$ and $A$ a scalar.

Comment: The formula you read is probably quite different, asserting that, if $X$ is standard gaussian, then $$\int_\Omega e^{\langle AX,X\rangle}dP=\frac1{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n}}\int_{\mathbb R^n}e^{\langle(A-\frac12I)x,x\rangle}dx$$ and stems directly from the fact that the PDF of $X$ is $$f_X(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n}}e^{-\frac12\langle x,x\rangle}$$ Exercise: Enumerate the mistakes in the formula you wrote.